# Code fires on Workbook_Open, but skips subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

Following code is in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call refreshAll
    MsgBox "Queries, Pivot Tables, and PivotCharts have been refreshed!"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("presentation").Activate
End Sub
```

I'm calling sub `refreshAll` and Excel "skips" it and executes the rest. `refreshAll` sub is located in Module1:

```
Public Sub refreshAll()
    query
    ThisWorkbook.refreshAll
End Sub
```

What's the problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the `Module1` if calling `refreshAll()`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Module1.refreshAll
    MsgBox "Queries, Pivot Tables, and PivotCharts have been refreshed!"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("presentation").Activate
End Sub
```

Without `Module1.RefreshAll()` , your code is executing  the `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll()` Method.

Comment: ‍♂️ well that would've taken me million years to figure out on my own. Thank you!

Comment: Mark this as the answer if it resolved your issue.